# How to debug Eclipse randomly crashing in MAC OS X?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm having some troubles with Eclipse/Chrome/Sublime. They Randomly crash (Simply closes and shows OS 'unexpected error').

I suspect this is related to Java JDK. There is a way to see these errors messages?

[This is the last Eclipse crash report](https://gist.github.com/Rodrigora/5bc3a5d2266bc47447a2), as requested.

[This Sublime crash just happened](https://gist.github.com/Rodrigora/1ed6be2518e3efba3ac2).

Comment: please post the crash report (`.crash` file) from `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` or maybe (unlikely) `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`,

Comment: @JohannesWeiß, crash report added!

Comment: seems like the JVM isn't handling a signal. Looks very much like a JVM on OS X bug to me. Presumably in syslog or in some file the JVM writes, you should also find more infomation, eg what signal it was.
Could be this (div by 0): http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/java/Java_Signal_Handling.SIGFPE.20080126.html

Comment: the Sublime crash is probably (but not for sure) an `NSException` within Sublime (a unrelated sublime text bug). syslog should also give you more information.